# em.persist does not fetch @ManyToOne existing data

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a Task that belongs to a TaskType (no cascade):

```
Task{
 @Id String id;
 
 @ManyToOne TaskType taskType;
}
```

When I create a new task, I assign a detached taskType with only the primary key:

```
Task task = new Task();
task.setTaskType(new TaskType("study"));  //"Study" task type already exists.
```

The TaskType entries pre-exists in the database. So, I only want to add new Task entries. When I create a new task with

em.persist(task);

As a response, I receive an entity where the taskType has only the primary key. The save is ok, I can check it in my database. The taskType was not modified or duplicated.

The problem is that when accessing task.getTaskType() it seems to be a reference of the actual object, i.e. only the PK is loaded. No LAZY query takes place since the default is EAGER.

When I'm updating a task with the exact same steps but using:

```
em.merge(task); //all data are available after this line
```

The task.taskType now holds all the information of the row.

I'm aware that I can first find and set an attached entity of type to my task:

```
task.setTaskType(em.find(TaskType.class, "study")); //this will fetch all data, not a reference
em.persist(task); // Now all info is available
```

Can someone give me an alternative or an one-liner solution? Or at least explain why this difference exists between em.persist and em.merge when referring a @ManyToOne entity without cascade?

Comment: persist assumes a new entity, where as merge does more checks to validate existing objects. Instead of `em.find` you could do `em.getReference` which will get you a lazy proxy of the object (and eventually a query).

Comment: Hi Deinum. I create a new entity with FK to an existing one (from a 'picklist'). What I want is after the save, to get all the data. I don't want to be optimal in performance terms, but the opposite: get the whole FK entity in response. Thanks.

Comment: Which you get with an `em.merge` already...

Comment: em.merge does not work with new entities. This will produce an error about detouched entity or not-null column. I want to execute a single save operation on the "Task". Some intermediate 'merging' is what I'm looking for! But in a one-liner solution. :) Or at least someone tell me, why em.persist stores the related entity, but does not eagerly merges it in the response.

Comment: Which is why you should use the `em.getReference` for the relation and **not** `new TaskType("ddfsjkfd")`. It stores it because it is a new entity and not an existing one.

Comment: I already said that by merging the existing one will work for me.But  I am not looking for this answer. I want to understand why em.persist vs em.merge with the same input, produces different output. I don't want to merge it myself. I want to understand the reason hibernate does it for em.mege and it doesn't do it for em.persist.

Comment: That I explained in my already first comment.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use merge in this case, but keep in mind that usually this is how it's supposed to be used: `Task managedTask = (Task) em.merge(task);`